# Name of interfaces that contain only one method definition

Tags: java, interface

As Marker Interface in java is an interface with no fields or methods within it.

Is there any special name for interfaces which contains only one method for example Interface `AutoCloseable`.

just curious ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Single Abstract Method OR [SAM Interface](https://stacktraceguru.com/java-8-functional-interface) or [Functional Interface](https://stacktraceguru.com/java-8-functional-interface) .

In Java 8 you can use [`@FunctionalInterface`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/FunctionalInterface.html) annotation on interfaces with a single abstract method. 
It is an informative annotation type used to indicate that an interface type declaration is intended to be a functional interface.
Annotation forcess to have exact one abstract mehtod.

Answer (score 1):

The interfaces with only one method are called **Single Abstract Method(SAM)** Interfaces.

With the advent of Java8, such interfaces are also called **Functional Interfaces**.